# AS3, Access of undefined property

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, undefined

I want to use the Base64 class written by Subhero in AS3, so I created a ActionScript Project containing two files: StringCompress.as and Base64.as. The code is as following. (The code of Base64.as is a bit long, but I just want to show you the function it contains.) However, in StringCompress.as, these two lines

```
return Base64.Encode(textBytes);
```

and

```
var textBytes:ByteArray = Base64.Decode(value);
```

have the same error "Access of undefined property Base64".

I don't know why, can anyone help me? Many Thanks!!!

//code

StringCompress.as code

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.errors.IOError;
import flash.events.Event;

public class StringCompress extends Sprite
{
    public function StringCompress()
    {

    }

    public static function Compress(value:String):String
    {
        var textBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        textBytes.writeUTFBytes(value);
        textBytes.compress();
        return Base64.Encode(textBytes);
    }


    public static function UnCompress(value:String):String
    {
        var textBytes:ByteArray = Base64.Decode(value);
        try
        {
            textBytes.uncompress();
        }
        catch(e:IOError){
            trace("The code to uncompress is not valid.");
        }
        return textBytes.toString();
    }
}
}
```

Base64.as code

```
/*
 *  A Base64 encoder/decoder implementation in Actionscript 3
 *  This work is made available under http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.0/de/deed.en
 *
 *  @author subhero@gmail.com
 *  @version 0.5
 */
package formatter {
// import ->
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.errors.EOFError;
// <- import

// Base64 ->
/*
*   A class used for transforming a ByteArray to a Base64-encoded string and vice versa.
*   Since the "built-in" class (mx.utils.Base64Encoder) is not documented yet, this class can be  
*   used for Base64 encoding/decoding in the meantime. 
*   The class will be deprecated as soon as Macromedia/Adobe decides to fully release the 
*   "native" AS3 Base64 class (Flex2 full release respectively). 
*   Its implementation is based upon a HowTo {@link http://www.kbcafe.com/articles/HowTo.Base64.pdf}, 
*   a Java implementation {@link http://ostermiller.org/utils/Base64.java.html} and an 
*   AS2-implementation by Jason Nussbaum {@link http://blog.jasonnussbaum.com/?p=108}
*
*/
public class Base64 {
    // mx.utils.StringUtil
    public static function isWhitespace(char:String):Boolean{
        switch (char){
            case " ":
            case "\t":
            case "\r":
            case "\n":
            case "\f":
                return true;    
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    // the Base64 "alphabet"
    private static var _b64Chars:Array=new Array(
        'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H',
        'I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
        'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X',
        'Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f',
        'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n',
        'o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',
        'w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3',
        '4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/'
    )
    // the reverse-lookup object used for decoding
    private static var _b64Lookup:Object=_buildB64Lookup();
    // the boolean to insert linebreaks after 76 chars into the Base64 encoded string
    private static var _linebreaks:Boolean;

    /*
    *   The class method for encoding an array of bytes to a Base64 encoded string. 
    *
    *   @param bArr A ByteArray containing values to encode
    *   @param linebreaks A boolean to insert a linebreak after 76 Base64-chars
    *   @return The Base64 encoded string
    *   
    */
    public static function Encode(bArr:ByteArray, linebreaks:Boolean=false):String
    {
        _linebreaks= linebreaks;
        return _encodeBytes(bArr);
    }

    /*
    *   The class method for decoding a Base64 encoded string to an array of bytes. 
    *
    *   @param str A Base64 encoded string
    *   @return An array of bytes
    *   
    */
    public static function Decode(str:String):ByteArray
    {
        return _decodeSring(str);
    }

    /*
    *   The private helper class method to build an object used for reverse B64 char lookup. 
    *
    *   @return An object with each B64 char as a property containing the corresponding value
    *   
    */
    private static function _buildB64Lookup():Object
    {
        var obj:Object=new Object();
        for (var i:Number=0; i < _b64Chars.length; i++)
        {
            obj[_b64Chars[i]]=i;
        } 
        return obj;
    }

    /*
    *   The private helper class method to determine whether a given char is B64 compliant. 
    *
    *   @param char A character as string (length=1)
    *   @return A boolean indicating the given char *is* in the B64 alphabet
    *   
    */
    private static function _isBase64(char:String):Boolean
    {
        return _b64Lookup[char] != undefined;
    }

    /*
    *   The private class method for encoding an array of bytes into a B64 encoded string. 
    *
    *   @param bs An array of bytes
    *   @return The B64 encoded string
    *
    *   @see formatter.Base64.Encode()
    *   
    */
    private static function _encodeBytes(bs:ByteArray):String
    {
        var b64EncStr:String = "";
        var bufferSize:uint;
        var col:uint=0;
        bs.position=0;
        while (bs.position < bs.length)
        {
            bufferSize= bs.bytesAvailable >= 3 ? 3 : bs.bytesAvailable;
            var byteBuffer:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
            bs.readBytes(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            b64EncStr += _b64EncodeBuffer(byteBuffer);
            col+=4;
            if (_linebreaks && col%76 == 0) {
                b64EncStr += "\n";
                col=0;
            }
        }
        return b64EncStr.toString();
    }

    /*
    *   The private class method for encoding a buffer of 3 bytes (24bit) to 4 B64-chars 
    *   (representing 6bit each => 24bit). 
    *
    *   @param buffer An array of bytes (1 <= length <= 3)
    *   @return The byte buffer encoded to 4 B64 chars as string
    *
    *   @see formatter.Base64._encodeBytes()
    *   
    */
    private static function _b64EncodeBuffer(buffer:ByteArray):String
    {
        var bufferEncStr:String = "";
        bufferEncStr += _b64Chars[buffer[0] >> 2];
        switch (buffer.length)
        {
            case 1 :
                bufferEncStr += _b64Chars[((buffer[0] << 4) & 0x30)];
                bufferEncStr += "=="; 
                break;
            case 2 : 
                bufferEncStr += _b64Chars[(buffer[0] << 4) & 0x30 | buffer[1] >> 4];
                bufferEncStr += _b64Chars[(buffer[1] << 2) & 0x3c];
                bufferEncStr += "=";
                break;
            case 3 : 
                bufferEncStr += _b64Chars[(buffer[0] << 4) & 0x30 | buffer[1] >> 4];
                bufferEncStr += _b64Chars[(buffer[1] << 2) & 0x3c | buffer[2] >> 6];
                bufferEncStr += _b64Chars[buffer[2] & 0x3F];
                break;
            default :   trace("Base64 byteBuffer outOfRange");  
        }           
        return bufferEncStr.toString();
    } 

    /*
    *   The private class method for decoding a string containing B64 chars to an array of bytes 
    *
    *   @param s The B64 encoded string
    *   @return A decoded array of bytes
    *
    *   @see formatter.Base64.Decode()
    *   
    */
    private static function _decodeSring(s:String):ByteArray
    {
        var b64EncString:String="" + s;
        var b64DecBytes:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
        var stringBuffer:String="";
        var lgth:uint=b64EncString.length;      
        for (var i:uint=0; i < lgth; i++)
        {
            var char:String=b64EncString.charAt(i);
            if (!isWhitespace(char) && (_isBase64(char) || char == "=")) {
                stringBuffer += char;
                if (stringBuffer.length == 4) {
                    b64DecBytes.writeBytes( _b64DecodeBuffer(stringBuffer) ); 
                    stringBuffer="";
                }
            }
        }
        b64DecBytes.position=0;
        return b64DecBytes;
    }

    /*
    *   The private class method for decoding a string buffer of 4 B64 chars 
    *   (each representing 6bit) to an array of 3 bytes. 
    *
    *   @param buffer A string containing B64 chars (length = 4)
    *   @return An array of bytes containing the decoded values
    *
    *   @see formatter.Base64._decodeBytes()
    *   
    */
    private static function _b64DecodeBuffer(buffer:String):ByteArray
    {
        var bufferEncBytes:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
        var charValue1:uint=_b64Lookup[buffer.charAt(0)];
        var charValue2:uint=_b64Lookup[buffer.charAt(1)];
        var charValue3:uint=_b64Lookup[buffer.charAt(2)];
        var charValue4:uint=_b64Lookup[buffer.charAt(3)];
        bufferEncBytes.writeByte(charValue1 << 2 | charValue2 >> 4);
        if (buffer.charAt(2) != "=") bufferEncBytes.writeByte(charValue2 << 4 | charValue3 >> 2);
        if (buffer.charAt(3) != "=") bufferEncBytes.writeByte(charValue3 << 6 | charValue4);
        return bufferEncBytes;
    }   
}
// <- Base64
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just didn't import base64 to class where you are using it. Add proper import line.

Edit: Put Base64.as into folder formatter, then "import formatter.Base64;" it will work, alternatively - in Base64.as, in first line "package formatter {" delete word "formatter" and then add "import Base64;" in StringCompress.as.

Comment: by "import Base64;" ? Both Base64.as and StringCompress.as are in the same directory. Sorry but I am a new comer to AS3. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is "package formatter {" it means that this class needs to be in the specific package (folder structure).

Comment: For simplicity, I removed "formatter", So I just "import Base64", and it worked, thanks!